# How to parse CMake-style arguments with python argparse?

Tags: python, cmake, argparse

I am using argparse to parse arguments of form `-D VAR=VALUE` or `--config VAR=VALUE` like this:

```
cmd.add_argument('--config', '-D', action = 'append', default = [])
```

I'd also like to support CMake-style variable assignments of form `-DVAR=VALUE`.

Are there good ways to achieve it with argparse without resorting to manual sys.argv tinkering?

Comment: As shown in the answer, `argparse` has no problem collecting these arguments.  But you'll have write your own code to convert `'VAR=VALUE'` to `{'VAR':VALUE}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, argparse supports all the common forms of cli arguments. Example:

```
import argparse
cmd = argparse.ArgumentParser()
cmd.add_argument('-D', action='append', default = [])
print(cmd.parse_args())
```

Usage:

```
$ python test_argparse.py -DVAR=val1 -DDEFINED_VAR -D ANOTHER_DEF -D VAR="string_val"
Namespace(D=['VAR=val1', 'DEFINED_VAR', 'ANOTHER_DEF', 'VAR=string_val'])
```

But you should probably set 2 different arguments to handle `-D` and `--config` options.